# Why is using IComparable slower than strings in comparisons?

Tags: c#, .net, string, performance

I'm using Mergesort to order 50.000.000 Strings and there are two different results depending on what parameter-type I use.

**Using the Interface IComparable:**

- 20226 ms

**Using Strings directly:**

- 10912 ms

Mergesort Code:

```
public class Mergesort2
{
    static private StringComparer comparer1 = StringComparer.Ordinal;
    public static void merge(IComparable[] a, IComparable[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi)
    {

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            aux[k] = a[k];
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            if (i > mid)
            {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else if (j > hi)
            {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else if (less(aux[j], aux[i]))
            {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else
            {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }

    }

    private static void sort(IComparable[] a, IComparable[] aux, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (hi <= lo)
        {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }

    public static void sort(IComparable[] a)
    {
        IComparable[] aux = new IComparable[a.Length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.Length - 1);
    }


    ///*********************************************************************
    ///  Helper sorting functions
    /// **********************************************************************

    // is v < w ?
    private static bool less(IComparable v, IComparable w)
    {
        return (comparer1.Compare(v, w) < 0);
    }

    // exchange a[i] and a[j]
    private static void exch(Object[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        Object swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///*********************************************************************
    ///  Index mergesort
    /// **********************************************************************
    /// </summary>
    // stably merge a[lo .. mid] with a[mid+1 .. hi] using aux[lo .. hi]
    private static void merge(IComparable[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi)
    {

        // copy to aux[]
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            aux[k] = index[k];
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            if (i > mid)
            {
                index[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else if (j > hi)
            {
                index[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else if (less(a[aux[j]], a[aux[i]]))
            {
                index[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else
            {
                index[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }
    }

    // return a permutation that gives the elements in a[] in ascending order
    // do not change the original array a[]
    public static int[] indexSort(IComparable[] a)
    {
        int N = a.Length;
        int[] index = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            index[i] = i;
        }

        int[] aux = new int[N];
        sort(a, index, aux, 0, N - 1);
        return index;
    }

    // mergesort a[lo..hi] using auxiliary array aux[lo..hi]
    private static void sort(IComparable[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (hi <= lo)
        {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, index, aux, lo, mid);
        sort(a, index, aux, mid + 1, hi);
        merge(a, index, aux, lo, mid, hi);
    }
}
```

This code produces the slow runtimes.

If I would change all **IComparable** types to **String** the performance would increase. Why are there so huge performance differences using the different types?

Comment: What if you make it generic and use `IComparable<T>` instead?

Comment: Yeah that's an option, but i don't really have a problem with using Strings, I just wanna understand the difference.

Comment: At least 100000000 casts are expensive. For example in `return (comparer1.Compare(v, w) < 0)`

Comment: If I use IComparable with my Quicksort implementation I get runtimes of 9927 ms and with Strings as parameter 8711 ms. So I can't explain the huge difference using Mergesort. Ofc also using 50 million as input.

Comment: StringComparer.Compare has different overloads for object and string. The string version is most likely highly optimized, whereas the object version merely gives you "regular .NET performance" (and given its general nature, is harder for the compiler to optimize).

Comment: What use is an `object` comparing `StringComparer` anyway? It seems to me it's merely fulfilling its contractual obligations offering the object interface. Why you'd want to use a `StringComparer` with anything other than string seems a mystery to me. I'm with @TimSchmelter on this. Pointless casts.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about performance: your test used strings that were small enough that the additional type checks required to use the non-generic `IComparable` interface, along with the use of interface-dispatch instead of virtual-dispatch (a low-level detail of virtual machines like .NET and the Java VM) were more expensive than the string comparisons. If you used strings with long common prefixes, the comparison operation would become the dominant performance cost and the gap between the two forms would close. **Edit:** running the test on a Release build of the code may close the gap as well (did not run the test locally, and I'm not sure what build the OP used for testing).

Now more importantly to the experiment as a whole, ***ignoring all other issues with the code***, I'll point out specifically the common practice for supporting "comparable" items in a generic manner in .NET.

1. Do not restrict the generic type `T` (might or might not be `string`, if fact it might or might not implement `IComparable`).
2. Use an `IComparer<T>` to compare elements. If the user passes a `null` for the `comparer` argument to one of the public methods, default to `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Here is the updated code:

```
public class Mergesort2
{
    public static void merge<T>(T[] a, T[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;

        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            aux[k] = a[k];
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            if (i > mid)
            {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else if (j > hi)
            {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else if (less(aux[j], aux[i], comparer))
            {
                a[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else
            {
                a[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }

    }

    private static void sort<T>(T[] a, T[] aux, int lo, int hi, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (hi <= lo)
        {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, aux, lo, mid, comparer);
        sort(a, aux, mid + 1, hi, comparer);
        merge(a, aux, lo, mid, hi, comparer);
    }

    public static void sort<T>(T[] a, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        T[] aux = new T[a.Length];
        sort(a, aux, 0, a.Length - 1, comparer);
    }


    ///*********************************************************************
    ///  Helper sorting functions
    /// **********************************************************************

    // is v < w ?
    private static bool less<T>(T v, T w, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return (comparer.Compare(v, w) < 0);
    }

    // exchange a[i] and a[j]
    private static void exch<T>(T[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        T swap = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = swap;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///*********************************************************************
    ///  Index mergesort
    /// **********************************************************************
    /// </summary>
    // stably merge a[lo .. mid] with a[mid+1 .. hi] using aux[lo .. hi]
    private static void merge<T>(T[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int mid, int hi, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {

        // copy to aux[]
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            aux[k] = index[k];
        }

        // merge back to a[]
        int i = lo, j = mid + 1;
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        {
            if (i > mid)
            {
                index[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else if (j > hi)
            {
                index[k] = aux[i++];
            }
            else if (less(a[aux[j]], a[aux[i]], comparer))
            {
                index[k] = aux[j++];
            }
            else
            {
                index[k] = aux[i++];
            }
        }
    }

    // return a permutation that gives the elements in a[] in ascending order
    // do not change the original array a[]
    public static int[] indexSort<T>(T[] a, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        int N = a.Length;
        int[] index = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            index[i] = i;
        }

        int[] aux = new int[N];
        sort(a, index, aux, 0, N - 1, comparer);
        return index;
    }

    // mergesort a[lo..hi] using auxiliary array aux[lo..hi]
    private static void sort<T>(T[] a, int[] index, int[] aux, int lo, int hi, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        if (hi <= lo)
        {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        sort(a, index, aux, lo, mid, comparer);
        sort(a, index, aux, mid + 1, hi, comparer);
        merge(a, index, aux, lo, mid, hi, comparer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I don't understand three things: **(1)** How do you know what kind of strings the OP used for testing? **(2)** I'd be grateful if you could point me to some literature/spec that says virtual dispatch is faster than "interface dispatch" in .NET. **(3)** Why would you default to `Comparer<T>.Default` for non-`IComparable` types? Personally I *would* restrict `T` to `IComparable`, since if that interface implementation is missing, then chances are that the type is not designed to be orderable (i.e. an ordering operation might have no meaning at all for that type).

Comment: I'm building the program as Release. But I think your code can't be compiled. I think you have mixed up IComparer<T> and IComparable<T>

Comment: @stakx It is completely valid in .NET to not mark a type as `IComparable<T>`, but instead rely only on the developer providing an implementation of `IComparer<T>`. One of the many examples of this is the `SortedList` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx

Comment: @user2025998 If `IComparable` appears in my code example, then I made a mistake. My intention is to use `IComparer<T>` as the only interface for comparing objects of type `T`.

Comment: @stakx: re #2, it is more complicated than that. The strategies chosen for interface dispatch vs virtual dispatch in .NET are tricky and have changed sublty over time. There are definitely scenarios where one is faster than the other but I wouldn't care to precisely characterize what they are off the top of my head. We did a lot of research on this in the early days of Roslyn but I don't recall the results and I have no ability to look them up now. Vance Morrison's 2006 article is a good place to start but might be out of date: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/03/13/550529.aspx

Answer (score -3):

IMHO, i would have to say simply this: the size of the object itself... so every time you declare a ICompare, which contains a bunch of extra properties, methods, etc, it takes more time, than if you declare the lesser String...

Comment: That's not correct at all. Also, take a look at String again. It has loads of methods, but as I said that is not at all relevant here.

Comment: Can you point us to some documentation that supports your answer? Where does it say that it takes longer to instantiate objects that have more properties and/or methods?

Comment: Are you really saying that casting `string` to `IComparable` allocates a new object? That's not right.

Comment: 1) 2 objects, 1 with 1 000 000 properties, other with 5. On separate web pages, make single instance of each object on the Page_Load event. In web page, place a message. Of COURSE it takes longer to create objects with more properties! metric it yourself if you'd like! a single or few milliseconds more... over 50 000 000 times, equates to seconds. 2) assembler level casting: 1-see if objects compatible, 2-create new object, 3-place properties of old in new, 4-destroy old at mem address X, 5-place new at same mem address... that is my knowledge anyway... again here, few milliseconds more!